# Juicer's food pusher's bottom just sliced off, now it's an empty cylinder

Tags: appliances

I want to fix it because I can't source another one right now - it's Breville JE-95. Anyway, I thought I'd get crafty and try to fix it, doing some plastic welding or gluing of a piece of plastic. I'd trace the shape from the bottom of the pusher, cut it out with a Dremel and combine the 2.

How would I go about the welding and what type of glue would be food-safe enough to be using for this purpose?

Comment: https://www.breville.com/us/en/parts-accessories/parts/sp0005818.html

Comment: Small appliance repair is off-topic here, but if plastic parts are cracking (I doubt that you actually meant _sliced_) it's likely that the plastic is degraded enough to make repair a fruitless ( :D ) venture. It'll crack again. Seek a new part from the manufacturer.

Comment: Just grab a 2-by-4, shave the edges so it fits into the juicer, and away you go.

Answer (score 2):

If buying the new one is not a viable option for you, then without knowing the exact type of plastic used in the old one, the only "food safe" multi-purpose adhesives will be either a silicone seal type, which is soft and flexible, so may not work under force, or a two part epoxy type hard bond material. That will take longer to cure, but will likely do the job and is what I would recommend.

This is just an example, not an endorsement, although Permabond is a well known company with a decent reputation.
https://www.permabond.com/2015/03/02/food-grade-adhesives-permabond/

It's worth noting however that the likelihood of your finding the Food Safe versions in a local hardware store are low, and the cost is going to be roughly the same as buying the new pusher on-line. So were it me, I would just replace it.